# How to share on TikTok in Swift

Tags: swift, video, sdk, share

I checked the [documentation](https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/ios-share) from TikTok SDK but it's only on Objective C. 
Can anyone tell me how to Connect the App delegate in Swift? This is the Objective C version

```
#import <TikTokOpenSDK/TikTokOpenSDKApplicationDelegate.h>
@implementation AppDelegate
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[TikTokOpenSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
        return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(nonnull NSURL *)url options:(nonnull NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {

    if ([[TikTokOpenSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]]
        ) {
        return YES;
    }    
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    if ([[TikTokOpenSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation]) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    if ([[TikTokOpenSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:nil annotation:nil]) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
@end
```

Comment: This may help: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_objective-c_into_swift

Comment: thanks! I am not importing Objective-C files but just writing more code on the AppDelegate.swift